# Bootstrap - Sidebar customization

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a website project using bootstrap for the first time and am experiencing a little problem I think veterans like you can help me with :)

The website has a top menu bar (fixed) which change when displayed on a small screen (like a mobile phone) - with a toggle button that display a sidebar menu.

I'm just trying to get access to the CSS underneath that sidebar but can't modify it without modifiying the main manu bar as well.
I don't know which class CSS i have to create/modify to get what I need :/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default redq" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
```

and a litte below...

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <a class="navbar-brand mobile pull-left" href="index.html#home" style="font-size:3vw;">MySite 2016</a>
            <a class="mobile-menu-close"><i class="fa  fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-list">
```

Any help or tip would be very much appreciated !
Thanks in advance for your help guys ;D

Answer (score 0):

I identified the issue and hope it will be more understandable that my previous piece of code.

The goal is actually to change the collapse sidebar width but only on mobile version

Putting the style directly in the style attritube works perfectly

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="width:100px;">
```

But if I try to put it in a CSS class definition, it doesn't work anymore

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
width: 100px;
}
```

Why is that happening !?

I really can't use the inline declaration because I need the use of @media in order to target only the mobile menu.

Answer (score 0):

That's it, I found it !

I post here the answer for anyone looking for the same result :D

```
#mobile-menu-wrap
{
    width: 10em;
}
```

This ID is found in script.js and give you full access to the sidebar (mobile) content ;)